# Is there a way to convert text to numbers in javascript then convert numbers into binary?

Tags: javascript, html, css, binary

I need a way to convert a letter into a number and then be able to convert a number into binary. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'a letter'?

Comment: Can you edit the question and show an example? By letter do you mean.. how to convert the string '123' to the number 123 or you literally mean A => 1? Needs more clarity.

Comment: *"I need a way to convert a letter into a number..."* Using what algorithm? Its Unicode code point (for instance, `A` = 65)? In some number base using letters (for instance, hex `A` = 10)? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert a character into it's ASCII representation, use `charCodeAt(0)`. For example:

```
'a'.charCodeAt(0); // 97
```

To convert a decimal number into a binary number, use `toString(2)`. For example:

```
(122).toString(2); // "1111010"
```

This method has some issues dealing with negative numbers though. let me know if you will be dealing with them.

Comment: question: what is the parameter you are entering, ex. (0), (2) ?

Comment: @josephT for toString, it' the base. E.G 16 for hex, 8 for octal 0/1 for an error.
for charCodeAt, it's the position in the string (0 for the first character, 'a'. 1 or more would be an error)

Comment: got it, so 0 is dec, 2 is binary right? That's pretty neat

Comment: @josephT Sorry for not explaining. charCodeAt() takes **the index** of the desired char to be converted, ex. "abc".charCodeAt(1) will get the ASCII of the 'b' char. Now, the toString() takes **the base** for which w need to convert this to.

Comment: @josephT 10 would be Decimal, since Decimal has numbers 0-9. 2 for Binary (0, 1). Without a parameter, the default is Decimal (10)

Comment: so you can even do something like this right? ... 'abc'.charCodeAt(0).toString(2); // 1111010

Comment: @josephT Sure!!

Comment: How would I be able to do this in html and convert text to numbers and then convert the numbers into binary?

Comment: @RealJoshLee Html is not a programming language, therefore has not logic in it to achieve such a functionality, you got to use JavaScript for this.

Comment: @AhmedHammad can I add a text box in html and have the java script pull the information and the js converts letters to numbers and then converts the numbers to binary.

Comment: @RealJoshLee Yes, this is the typical way to do it. Learn more about Html <input> tags, and JavaScript DOM https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp

Comment: @AhmedHammad one last thing. Is is possible to make java script generate text in a text box <input> if so how?

Comment: @RealJoshLee Sure! `document.querySelector("#yourInputId").value = "your desired text";`

Comment: The question didn't ask for ASCII but if you intend to automagically convert from UTF-16 (see [charCodeAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt)) to ASCII, I suggest at least a code comment saying so and including the range of characters it is valid for.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
parseInt("12").toString(2)
```

Result:

```
"1100"
```